# FFMPEG only 8bit, cant get 10 bit

Tags: ffmpeg, x265

I have a 10bit uhd HVEC video I want to convert to x265 10bit. I've compiled the newest version of FFmpeg and x265. But even if I set main10 I only get 8 bit and no hdr10. The video is 10bit.

I tried to install FFmpeg with apt and if I do that 10 bit works. But the version is too old. So what am I doing wrong? The EXACT same command makes a 10bit hdr video with the apt version.

Why is FFmpeg refusing 10 bit?

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.

```
sudo apt-get install libnuma-dev && \ cd ~/ffmpeg_sources && \
wget -O x265.tar.bz2 bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265_git/get/master.tar.bz2 && \
tar xjvf x265.tar.bz2 && \
cd multicoreware*/build/linux && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" -DENABLE_SHARED=off ../../source && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make && \
make install
```

This is the guide i used to compile:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Comment: Here you go. But as i said this command works fine in the APT version of ffmpeg v6.ffmpeg -i input -map 0:v:0 -c:v libx265 -preset fast -crf 22 -profile:v main10 -x265-params level-idc=51:high-tier=1:hdr10=1 -map 0:a:0 -c:a:0 copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy output.mkv

Comment: IMHO `make install` also should have `sudo` in front

Comment: Why sudo? I dont get any errors when i compile. Seems like i only compile 8 bit or something.

Comment: @DwightSchrute Try adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p10le` before `output.mkv`.

Comment: Already tried it. I think the compile guide only compiles 8 bit. So i think thats the problem. yuv420p10le doesnt exist so has to be that.